# Getting Syntax error while writing inTestRunner class with Cucumber - Java

Tags: cucumber

Issue: TestRunner  with cucumber jvm class getting syntax error:
    Cucumber set up is done. I ran the cucumberrunner class and feature file was picked and ran gave me the error to add missing implementation.But when I add a class with the detail methods. I get syntax error. Not able to understand the error:
    Error as below:

```
Illegal modifier for parameter user_is_on_home_page; only final is permitted    stepdefinition_test.java    /cucumber-jvm-maven/src/main/java/stepdefinition    line 12 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "message_displayed_as_successful", AnnotationName expected after this token   stepdefinition_test.java    /cucumber-jvm-maven/src/main/java/stepdefinition    line 30 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "user_enters_Username_and_Password", AnnotationName expected after this token stepdefinition_test.java    /cucumber-jvm-maven/src/main/java/stepdefinition    line 24 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "user_is_on_home_page", AnnotationName expected after this token  stepdefinition_test.java    /cucumber-jvm-maven/src/main/java/stepdefinition    line 12 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "user_navigates_in_home_page", AnnotationName expected after this token   stepdefinition_test.java    /cucumber-jvm-maven/src/main/java/stepdefinition    line 18 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements    stepdefinition_test.java    /cucumber-jvm-maven/src/main/java/stepdefinition    line 12 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement  stepdefinition_test.java    /cucumber-jvm-maven/src/main/java/stepdefinition    line 18 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement  stepdefinition_test.java    /cucumber-jvm-maven/src/main/java/stepdefinition    line 24 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement  stepdefinition_test.java    /cucumber-jvm-maven/src/main/java/stepdefinition    line 30 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete NormalAnnotation   stepdefinition_test.java    /cucumber-jvm-maven/src/main/java/stepdefinition    line 12 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete NormalAnnotation   stepdefinition_test.java    /cucumber-jvm-maven/src/main/java/stepdefinition    line 18 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete NormalAnnotation   stepdefinition_test.java    /cucumber-jvm-maven/src/main/java/stepdefinition    line 24 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete NormalAnnotation   stepdefinition_test.java    /cucumber-jvm-maven/src/main/java/stepdefinition    line 30 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert "[ ]" to complete Dimension    stepdefinition_test.java    /cucumber-jvm-maven/src/main/java/stepdefinition    line 12 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert "[ ]" to complete Dimension    stepdefinition_test.java    /cucumber-jvm-maven/src/main/java/stepdefinition    line 18 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert "[ ]" to complete Dimension    stepdefinition_test.java    /cucumber-jvm-maven/src/main/java/stepdefinition    line 24 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert "[ ]" to complete Dimension    stepdefinition_test.java    /cucumber-jvm-maven/src/main/java/stepdefinition    line 30 Java Problem
void[] is an invalid type   stepdefinition_test.java    /cucumber-jvm-maven/src/main/java/stepdefinition    line 12 Java Problem
```

Feature file below
Feature: Calculator

```
Scenario: Login
Given user is on home page
When user navigates in home page
And user enters '<Username>' and '<Password>'
Then Message displayed as successful

|Username | Password |
| triptitest | sleep345|
```

Cucumber file
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

```
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        glue = "stepdefinition"
        ,features = "Feature/calculator.feature"
        )

public class cucumberunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}


POM xml:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xxxxxx.bdd</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-test</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>XXXXX</name>
  <url>XXXXX</url>
  <dependencies>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>    
  </dependencies>
   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>
                    maven-compiler-plugin
                </artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Testrunner file
    package stepdefinition;

```
import cucumber.api.PendingException;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.*;

public class stepdefinition_test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        @Given("^user is on home page$")
        public void user_is_on_home_page() throws Throwable {
            // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
            throw new PendingException();
        }

        @When("^user navigates in home page$")
        public void user_navigates_in_home_page() throws Throwable {
            // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
            throw new PendingException();
        }

        @When("^user enters '<Username>' and '<Password>'$")
        public void user_enters_Username_and_Password() throws Throwable {
            // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
            throw new PendingException();
        }

        @Then("^Message displayed as successful$")
        public void message_displayed_as_successful() throws Throwable {
            // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
            // For automatic transformation, change DataTable to one of
            // List<YourType>, List<List<E>>, List<Map<K,V>> or Map<K,V>.
            // E,K,V must be a scalar (String, Integer, Date, enum etc)
            throw new PendingException();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Add code from the step definition java class also...

Comment: I have added the code. The issue is I have not implemented code just copied the error still getting the error

Comment: Your step definition class is wrong, it will not compile. You have placed the stepdef methods inside the main() method. Take out all the methods outside the main() method into the class body. Also remove the main method() in cucumber runner class, it serves no purpose.